# Reagent/ClojureScript - multiple component aspect updates

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have a select component which shows a label and the associated options. There is a separate 'language' select which should choose the language of the display. On change it updates both `@language` which choses the label language and `@search-language-options` which provides the options to the select.
The label updates as expected, but the options list does not - it remains as originally initialised.

```clojure
;; search-languages -> vector
;; return the languages referenced in the data for options use

(defn search-languages []
  (let [options (list (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:choice-any]))]
  (if (= @language :or) (concat options (vec (set (map (partial get-field "lang") parsed-json))))
    (concat options (vec (set (map (partial get-field "langTranslated") parsed-json)))))))

(def search-language-options (r/atom (search-languages)))

;; filter component -> component
;; create a select
(defn select-filter-component [label value options]
  [:div {:class "form-group"}
  [:label {:class "control-label" :for label} label]
  [:select {:id label :class "form-control" :value @value :on-change #(reset! value (-> % .-target .-value))}
    (for [opt options]
      ^{:key opt} [:option {:value opt} opt])]])

;; lang-select -> component
;; choose display language 
(defn lang-select []
[:div {:class "form-control" }
  [:select {:id :en :value @language :on-change (fn [e]
    (reset! language (.. e -target -value))
    (reset! search-language-options (search-languages)))
    }
  ^{:key :en} [:option {:value :en} "English"]
  ^{:key :fr} [:option {:value :fr} "Français"]
  ^{:key :es} [:option {:value :es} "Español"]
  ^{:key :or} [:option {:value :or} "Original language"]
  ]])

;; filter form
;; filter the results
(defn filter-form []

[:form {:class "form-inline"}
[search-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:search] ) search-text]

[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:language] ) search-language @search-language-options]
[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:gender] ) gender ["Any" "M" "F"]]
[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:continent/title] ) continent ["Any" "Europe"]]
[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:country] ) placeTranslated ["Any" "Austria" "Switzerland" "Germany"]]
[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:literaryForm] ) literaryForm ["Any" "Drama" "Poetry" "Prose: fiction" "Prose: non-fiction" ]]
[select-filter-component (tr {:dict ld} [@language :en] [:genre] ) genre ["Any" "Short story" "Novella" "Graphic Novel"]]
[reset-button]]

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the `[:option...]` elements in `select-filter-component` don't change?  If that's what you mean, it is hard to tell from the code posted why they don't change because those options are rendered based on the props passed into `select-filter-component`, and you haven't shown how you are calling `select-filter-component`.  Specifically this code is completely dependent on the `options` prop passed in:

```
(for [opt options]
   ^{:key opt} [:option {:value opt} opt])
```

(Side note: though it doesn't matter here, note that `for` is lazy, so if you ever reference an atom in a `for` note that you'll have to wrap it in a `doall` or the atom won't be referenced during rendering and your component won't update when the atom updates.)

If you mean that selecting different options with the mouse doesn't work, then that is because you have commented out the `on-change` handler.

Comment: The [:option...] elements in select-filter-component don't change. I added in the `select-filter-component` calling code to the snippets. Ignore the `(tr ...) this just does i18n stuff.

Comment: Generally, swapping out the options seems to work on a small example in my repo.  Try some log statements in each component to see if they are rerendering with the data you expect.  (Note, when you swap out the options, you are swapping not only the display name but also the value.  The value atom will have to be swapped to or the selected value will be invalid and you'll lose the selection state.)